# Open GL texture flickering with GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER at GL_NEAREST

Tags: opengl, textures, flicker

I have a simple OpenGL program built with GLUT that draws a few buildings, have a keyboard controlled moving camera, and I am trying to texture the ground.  The animation is smooth.

The problem I have is with texturing mapping the ground.  Two separate issues with two separate approaches

1) If I use glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST); then I have no
flickering when I zoom out to far away.  But the issue is when I zoom out from far, it appears as a single solid color.

From far:

[image: GL_LINEAREST_MIPMAP from far]

From close:

[image: GL_LINEAREST_MIPMAP from close]

2) If I use, glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); then I have a lot of flickering
when I zoom out to far away as I move, almost look like a TV noise when you are out of tune.
But stationary, it looks more natural.

From far:

[image: GL_NEAREST from far]

From close:

[image: GL_NEAREST from close]

**Questions:** What would be a simple way from my existing code to get the best of both worlds?  Looking natural from far, and no flickering of the texture as I move.  Thank you.

Here is the relevant code:

```
GLuint  grassTextureId;
GLfloat GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH = 1000.0f;

void Display()
{   
    glLoadIdentity();
    camera.Update();
    ...
    FlatGroundPlane_Draw(void);
    ...

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void FlatGroundPlane_Draw(void) 
{   

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);            
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, grassTextureId); // call glBindTexture before glBegin     
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  

    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2d(0, 0); 

    GLdouble textCoord = GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH;

    glVertex3f( -GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH, 0, -GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH);

    // go beyond 1 for texture coordinate so it repeats and tiles
    glTexCoord2d(0, textCoord); 
    glVertex3f( -GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH, 0, GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH);

    glTexCoord2d(textCoord, textCoord); 
    glVertex3f( GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH, 0, GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH);

    glTexCoord2d(textCoord, 0); 
    glVertex3f( GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH, 0, -GROUND_PLANE_WIDTH);        

    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}

void Initialise()
{

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
    glClearDepth(1.0f);    
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);   

    modelParser = new ModelParser();
    // grass texture is 1024x1024
    // from http://seamless-pixels.blogspot.ca/2012_10_01_archive.html
    grassTextureId = modelParser->LoadTiledTextureFromFile("./Grass/Grass_1024.ppm");

}

void ModelParser::UploadTiledTexture(unsigned int &iTexture, const RGBImage &img)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &iTexture); // create the texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, iTexture);

    // Issue 1: no flickering, but appear solid color from far away 
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


    // Issue 2: flickering noise during movement but appear realistic from far away
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


    // the texture would wrap over at the edges (repeat)
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, img.Width(), img.Height(), GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.Data());
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    ...
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    ...
    glutDisplayFunc(&GLUT::Display);
    ...
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Since you are building mipmaps, you might consider `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST` for your minification filter instead. This will use the mipmaps for LOD selection (get rid of a lot of the flickering) but will sample using nearest neighbor filtering. When you use linear filtering, it would also look a lot nicer if you used linear interpolation between LODs (`GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`); the abrupt lines visible between each of the texture LODs in the second screenshot would be smoothed out and the solid green color in the first might even go away.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for your suggestion, I tried GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST, it gave me some flickering when I am close than GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR and GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST, both which had no flickering.  But with all three, when I zoomed out, I still see a solid green color.

Comment: The solid green color is because the level of the mipmap being used is solid green. This is expected since it is averaging pixels as it is built. If you don't want this, consider hand-creating the different texture levels instead of auto-generating them from the high-res texture. That way you can have some notion of "grass" at any zoom level.

Comment: @Dithermaster.  Thanks, so if a 1024x1024 pixel texture is used to tile a 1x1 area, and I have a 1000x1000 square area.  The 1x1 area looks good from y=5, and I have a 1000x1000 square area that I want to view from let's say y=400, how many levels of manually crafted texture would I then need?

Mipmap images is built from 1024x1024 down to 1x1, so there is only 10 levels, how would that translate into a limit on how high I can go without everything going solid green?

Comment: You can set the minimum/maximum texture LOD used for filtering, as well as an LOD bias. Texel vs. sample size will no longer be a close fit if you do this, but you can avoid sampling from the lowest 1x1 LOD. Trilinear filtering should honestly take care of this though.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks Andon.  What OpengGL call do I have to make to avoid sampling from the lowest 1x1 LOD when I have a mipmap built with gluBuild2DMipmaps.  I almost think I would need to dynamically change how often I tile.  If a 1x1 grass tile looks good from y=5 at 1024x1024 resolution, then if I zoom out to see all 1000x1000 tiles at once at y=200, then I will end up with each tile only taking up 1 pixel.  If I don't reduce the number of tiles at y=200, then there is no way it could look natural right?